# normalize.css doesn't work in my PHP file

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem right here. I'm developing a Webpage in PHP from scratch, currently I started with HTML and imported normalize.css in my index.view.php file, it looks like this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>AlfonsoIMa</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<meta owner="Alfonso Izaguirre Martínez">
<meta author="Alfonso Izaguirre Martínez">
```

I'm using XAMPP and PHP7. I imported then refreshed my localhost and I didn't work. My code looks fine so, maybe the issue it's with XAMPP... Any solution?

Comment: Any errors on browser console? Specifically 404 'not found' errors?

Comment: I think there is no problem with the html code. Probably there is some problem with the path to this file

Comment: As Toby said, you have to sow us browser console.

Comment: The browser console is not throwing any error or exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the css is called from the correct **relative postition.**

Try this instead:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">`

Comment: Nope, I tried and console didn't find the css file. My syntax is correct.